# append strings with order

Tags: vimscript

The original text:

```
line1
lline2

line
```

I want to add strings into the below format:

```
line1
lline2
x
y
z

line
```

Move cursor at the 2th line,and `ctrl`+`;`,enter into ex mode:

```
for s in ['x','y','z']
    call append('.',s)
endfor
```

Press enter key now,what i get is as below:

```
line1
lline2
z
y
z

line
```

Why the order is `z`,`y`,`x`,instead of `x`,`y`,`z`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you `append` the `x`, it is on line 3 but *your cursor is still on line 2*. So when you subsequently `append` the `y`, it is also placed on line 3, pushing the `x` down.

Try moving your cursor one line further down and then adding the lines above the cursor instead:

```
for s in ['x','y','z']
    call append(line('.') - 1, s)
endfor
```

As [@ChristianBrabandt points out](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/28229/append-strings-with-order/28230#comment51333_28230), you could also just reverse the list:

```
for s in reverse(['x','y','z'])
    call append('.', s)
endfor
```

However, an even better solution is to pass the list directly to [`append()`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#append%28%29) and dispense with the loop entirely. (Thanks to [@LucHermitte for the reminder!](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/28229/append-strings-with-order#comment51335_28230))

```
call append('.', ['x', 'y', 'z'])
```

Comment: alternatively, you could reverse the list

Comment: You could also simply use `append('.', ['x', 'y', 'z'])`